# PHP Variables - same var, different values ok?

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

Basic PHP Question...

Is it okay to use the same variable name ($image) over and over again in the same php file, if you keep changing it's value? Or do you need to do $image1, $image2 and so on...?

It's working to do it with the same variable/different values, but I'm not sure if it's a bad practice? (I'm still learning, obviously.)

Here's a simplified example:

```
$image = get_field('image_3');

echo $image

...

$image = get_field('image_5');

echo $image
```

Also, I'm referring to what I assume are global variables. The variable is not set within an individual function. Do I need to unset the variable each time if I do it this way? Or is this ok?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's a bad practice, because it's hard to understand what is it currently inside the `$image` when reading the source code.

However, it's perfectly valid PHP code, variables in imperative languages like the Algol family of languages are meant to be changed.

By the way, you almost never need to `unset()` the value of a variable, only in clever tricks or when working with really large datasets.

Comment: Thank you. This was a clear answer -- Bad practice, but technically valid. Also, appreciate the tip on not needing to use unset().

Answer (score 1):

As PHP is not a typed language, you may do this.

**Typed (Java):**

```
float i = 3.563
string s = "3.563"
```

**Non-Typed (PHP):**

e.g on Line 10: `i = 3.563;`

Then, further down: `i = "3.563";`

In a non-typed programming language, it is up to you, to not having a chaos with your var-names. My advice is:

Basically, it is allowed, but...

If suddenly, you'll put a boolean or a float in previously stringed variable, I'd say, that's not clean programming.

You may encounter problems in bigger applications. Here's why:

For you as a programmer, it's cleaner to create another variable for other values, than e.g.

`$image = get_field('image_3');`

and further down you say: `$image = true;`

Will you remember on line 10'000 (or as commented: on line 42) what kind of value you had in the `$image` var?
But if you have an `$image` var and a `$someThingIstrue` var, you'll see by the name of the variable, what it's for.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. In a really large page that will get unwieldy.

Comment: I should say that the variable scope spanning 10000 lines is not just a "bigger application", it's a horrible unstructured application.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `var_dump()` for the best practice and also you may use `unset()` when it remains unhelpful